# How multipassd should be restarted to get multipass commands fuctional again?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, multipass

Currently I can't run multipass shell, it shows the following in the terminal:

> ```
> $ multipass shell ubuntu-test
> shell failed: cannot connect to the multipass socket
> Please ensure multipassd is running and '/var/snap/multipass/common/multipass_socket' is accessible
> ```

It seems that I need to restart multipassd, but how should I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This service is provided by Snap, so it should restarted as follows:

```
sudo snap restart multipass.multipassd
```